# Group by with sum doesn't return correct result

Tags: mysql, sql

Say a table has this schema :

```
grp   |   number
1     |     10    
1     |     10    
1     |     10    
2     |     30    
2     |     30    
3     |     20
```

Note that each unique grp has a unique number even if there are more than 1 grp. I'm looking to sum all numbers for each unique grp.

So I want to group my table by grp to have this :

```
grp   |   number
1     |     10    
2     |     30    
3     |     20
```

And then get the sum which is now 60, but without grouping it gets me 110 as it calculates the sum of everything without grouping. All in one query, with no sub-queries if possible.

I've tried doing the following :

```
SELECT sum(number) as f
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY grp
```

But this doesn't work, it returns multiple results and not the single result of the sum. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185135/discussion-on-question-by-gumakettell-group-by-with-sum-doesnt-return-correct-r).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use subquery to select unique records & do the `sum`:

```
select sum(number)
from (select distinct grp, number
      from table t
     ) t;
```

Comment: And with no subqueries? :)

Comment: The main query does not do a database lookup here, it just sums the select statement of the subquery, so I don't think this will be a performance issue. Do you have a reason why you would want it to be without subqueries?

Comment: @rpi because all of this is already inside a subquery, I would have 3 subqueries, but I'm not saying this answer is false ;-)

Comment: @gumakettell I really don't think this is possible without a subquery.

Comment: @gumakettell, I think you should have mentioned this in your question, because then people know why you don't do it in your application code

Answer (score 1):

If you group by the group, then you'll get one result for each group. And it won't take into account the fact that you only want to use the value from each group once.

To get your desired result, taking one row from each group, you first need to make a subquery selecting DISTINCT group/number combinations from the table, and then SUM that.

```
SELECT 
  sum(`number`) as f
FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT `grp`, `number` FROM table1) g
```

This will output `60`.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8a3b346041731a4b4c85f4e151c10f70

Comment: I want to group all of the groups created by your group by, that is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @gumakettell I updated the answer to reflect the clarified requirements